# Error in Launching application with different DB profile defined in the spring config server into client spring boot project

Tags: docker, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, launching-application

I am trying to develop a microservice and deployment for two different regions. Two different region using two different database. So  for using that, I created one spring cloud config server and defined database property for two different profiles,

Here Is my spring cloud config server project details, Created config folder in src/main/resources and add two files,

bootstrap-vcu.properties file containing,

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/milleTech_users
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgresql
```

bootstrap-sp.properties file containing,

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/espace
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgresql
```

Application.properties containing,

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native
```

Bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=localhost:8888
```

Folder structure for config server is as following,

[image]

And my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And created separate project for spring cloud config client,

Config client project application.properties file is like,

```
server.port=8080
spring.cloud.config.uri=localhost:8888
```

And launching client application like ,

```
java -jar -Dsping.profiles.active=vcu ConfigClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

**But getting error as**

```
"Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not 
specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured"
```

**Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename DbVcu.properties into application-DbVcu.properties and move it to src/main/ressources folder.

Comment: Ok . Let me try sir.

Comment: If it doesn't work, enable logging and look for loaded properties files to check if bootstrapping behave as you expect.

Comment: Its not working . I updated my question. Still only showing "spring.datasource.url". I didn't understood that logging enabling in your comment.

Comment: In fact, given your configuration files I'm not sure that you understand how spring-cloud-config works and the distinction between the server and client part spring-cloud-config. Read this article that can clarify things : https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

Comment: Yes, I found those link. I changing into bootstrap-vcu.properties / yml , Since spring cloud config server defining properties in bootstrap. And also it loaded before application.properties file loading. Now i have only one confusion that I documentation containing to add by git reference. "spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri". Here I don't want to give as git reference.  I am preferring only property file (bootstrap-<profile-name>.yml/properties). Let me know if this approach is working for me.

Comment: Hi Prince, again I think you misunderstood spring-cloud-config. First of all because the spring.cloud.config.uri property is ignored in application.properties. It must be in bootstrap.properties. Then, because the bootsrap file must be called bootstrap.properties (or .yml) not bootstrap-<profile-name>.yml / properties. Finally because I do not see any dependency on `spring-cloud-starter-config` nor `spring-cloud-config-client` in your pom, essential to download conf from the spring cloud server.

Repeat the tutorial and if it works, add your code in it.

Comment: Yes , I updated with new addings. But still getting like ""Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not 
specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured"". I updated my question. Can you please look on this?

Comment: Reason is displaying as "Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class".

Comment: yaa..That question is also mine. I explored and add result as answer. Now I am in right track. Thank you for your response and spending time with me Mr Sebastien Helbert